# Non-linear least squares solver to solve a system of non-linear equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, least-squares

Can I use a non-linear least squares solver to find the solutions of a system of non-linear equations?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares): "The method of least squares is a standard approach to the approximate solution of overdetermined systems, i.e., sets of equations in which there are more equations than unknowns."

Now, since a "normal" system of non-linear equations should be in the set of overdetermined systems (in the degenerate case where the number of unknowns is equal to the number of equations), can I deduce I can use a non-linear least squares solver for this purpose?

This question comes from the fact that I have to use the [Google Ceres Solver](http://ceres-solver.org/solving.html) library that only seems to provide methods for non-linear least squares.

Comment: As explained [here][1], the answer should be "yes".


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401539/can-i-solve-a-system-of-non-linear-equations-with-google-ceres-solver